# Operator << in a class for queue

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have a small problem with defining my operator:

The code for the operator is:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outs, const IntQueue& queue)
{
    NodePtr temp = queue.head;
    while(temp->link != NULL)
    {
        outs << temp->data;
        outs << " ";
    }
    outs << endl;
    return outs;
}
```

I want the operator to display temp->data for all nodes in the queue and also the last node(which points to NULL). I don't know how I can modify the while loop so it also writes out the last item (that points to NULL).

Hope I made myself clear.

Cheers.

Comment: Please post `IntQueue`'s definition.

Comment: It looks like you are not "advancing" `temp` in your loop. This is bad (infinite loop). And do you just want to print "NULL" for the `NULL`? Otherwise how do you want it to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ostream& operator <<( ostream& outs, const IntQueue& queue )
{
    for ( NodePtr temp = queue.head; temp; temp = temp->link )
    {
        outs << temp->data;
        outs << " ";
    }

    outs << endl;

    return outs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a do-while loop so that it wouldn't check for the NULL until after it had done the operation the last time.

I would imagine this would allow you to print out NULL as the final value.

Comment: And `temp->data` when `temp` is `NULL` causes what?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outs, const IntQueue& queue)
{
    NodePtr temp = queue.head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        outs << temp->data;
        outs << " ";
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    outs << endl;
    return outs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to correct :

- As pointed out in the comments, inside the while loop make sure to advance the pointer with something like

  temp = temp->link;
- Edit your loop to be a do-while loop. In that way you're sure that it'll print out even the last node.
- Once you use a do-while loop, you'll need to add an additional NULL check on temp to handle the 'empty' list case.

Finally, as an additional point, you could consider overloading the '<<' operator for the Node object itself. That way your code to print out the entire queue would just be for iterating over the queue as shown below :

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outs, const IntQueue& queue)
{
    Node* temp = queue.head;
    if(NULL != temp) {
        do
        {
            outs << temp;
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        while(temp->link != NULL);
    }
    return outs;
}
```